# pdflatex from Miktex crashes

Tags: pdftex, miktex, miktex2.9

I just installed Miktex (2.9, 64-bit, the default download) on this machine and tried using it with Texmaker but the compilation seems to crash. I tried running pdflatex from a terminal and got the following:

```
ERROR: Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

ERROR: Info:
path="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2
c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb"
ERROR: Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\MemoryMappedFile\win\winMemoryMappedFile.cpp
ERROR: Line: 83
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? I tried reinstalling but it didn't help.

Comment: Normally this means that something is open, e.g. the console, and blocks the fndb.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, so I cannot use pdflatex while the console is open? Let me try....

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You were right! Would you mind adding this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this error means that some miktex tool is open (today mostly the console) and blocks the fndb.